# Looking for an episode of Farscape where Rygel goes back to his planet with Chiana and Ka Jothee

Tags: episode-identification, farscape

Has anyone seen the episode of *Farscape* where Rygel goes back to his planet with Chiana and Ka Jothee? I can´t find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such episode.  Dealing with multiple Hynerian puppets was deemed to be too much of a technical challenge, so more than [two at a time](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Fractures) were never attempted.

However, in the [very first issue](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_King) of the Farscape comic book series, those three characters, Rygel, Chiana, and Jothee indeed do travel to Hyneria to try to get Rygel his throne back.  (The story arc continues for three more issues after that.)  That must be what you are thinking of.

Comment: Thanks :) it's funny I can't shake the feeling that I saw it, I have memorie of some scenes, rygel on moya being called to go to his planet, then with D'argo dead his son went with chiana. And chryton and erin being tricked by scorpious using their son...

Comment: @MarleneSilva I think those plot points cement that story in the comics. AFAIK, The last of the TV stuff was "Peacekeeper Wars", where the son was born at the end.